# Create complex Json using Entity Framework C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, entity

I have two tables:

Products

```
ProductId | ProductName
__________|____________
       1  | iPhone5
       2  | iPhone6
       3  | iPhone6s
```

Images

```
Id |    ImagePath     | ProductId
___|__________________|___________
1  | /images/231.jpg  |    2
2  | /images/432.jpg  |    2
3  | /images/111.jpg  |    1
```

I want get Json looks like

```
{  
   "id":"2",
   "ProductName":"iPhone6"
},
"Images":[  
   {  
      "Id":"1",
      "ImagePath":"/images/231.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"2",
      "ImagePath":"/images/432.jpg"
   }
]
```

So I want to get all images of each Product using Entity Framework. I tried using join:

```
 var ads = db.Products.
      Join(db.Images, 
           x=>x.ProductId,
           cm=>cm.ProductId,
           (x ,cm) => new {
            Ads = x, 
            Images = cm
      }).
      Select(d => new {
            d.Ads.AdId,
            d.Images.ImagePath,
       }).
      Where(x => x.ProductId== 2).
      ToList();
```

**And my Json**

```
[
    {
        "AdId":2,
        "ImagePath":"/images/231.jpg"
    },
    {
        "AdId":2,
        "ImagePath":"/images/432.jpg"
    }
]
```

My Product and Image models:

```
public class Product{

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image{

    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your model definition for `Product`, and `Image`, along with how you are modelling the relationship between these 2 entities? Because if that is done correctly, then, you don't have to perform the join, and rather need to simply grab a `Product`, and serialize that (maybe using `Json.NET`).

Comment: updated, take a look please

Comment: You rather might want to do a group join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may explicitly model the `one-to-many` relationship between the `Product`, and `Image` like following:

```
public class ProductConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfig()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Images).WithRequired(i => i.Product).HasForeignKey(i => i.ProductId);
    }
}
```

And add this configuration in the `DbContext`, as follows:

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductConfig());            
    }
}
```

Once the relationship is modeled correctly then you can use:

```
var prod = myDbContext.Products.Find(2);
```

OR

```
var prod = myDbContext.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == 2);
```

OR

```
var prod = myDbContext.Products.Where(p => p.Id == 2);
```

to get the product and simply serialize that as follows:

```
var iPhone6Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(iPhone6, Formatting.Indented);
```

The `Images` associated will b loaded during serialization as those are marked virtual. You don't need to perform and explicit join. The key here is that you need to **serialize before disposing the `DbContext` instance**, otherwise the feature of lazy loading may not work, and you may face some undesired error.

You may also additionally mark the `Product` property in `Image` as `JsonIgnore` to exclude that from serialization and avoid reference loop.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public int ProductId { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public Product Product { get; set; }
```

Then the `JSON` you should have is following:

```
{  
    "id":"2",
    "ProductName":"iPhone6",
    "Images":[  
       {  
          "Id":"1",
          "ImagePath":"/images/231.jpg"
       },
       {  
          "Id":"2",
          "ImagePath":"/images/432.jpg"
       }
    ]
}
```

I think that too serves your purpose.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It gives me an error 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.' This thing works if I set this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: @IgorLevashov I think you are trying to serialize after disposing the `DbContext` instance. Try to serialize before that. I have also updated my answer with few additional pointers that might be helpful for you.